# Add background color to area between coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The case:
I have a image over a beach. On that beach, people can rent chairs. I'm developing a system, where the owner of the chairs can draw on the image because some spots on the beach are more expensive than others. So people can see what it cost in different areas of the beach.

The way it works is:
When he clicks on the map, i draw lines between the coordinates, and when he is finished drawining and have made a rectangle or a polygon, this is the subarea where the chairs cost a specific amount. I want to highlight this area, and fade out the rest of the image.

I have already made it so he can draw on the map and then I connect the lines between the coordinates. It is the highlight part I have trouble with:-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't invent the wheel. There are hundreds of [image cropping and selection tools](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-crop-image-plugin/) build in JS.

I'd go with something really simple, alike [**Cropper** plugin for jQuery](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/), it does exactly what you are asking about. If you need to understand how it works - look the source code.

Comment: Yes, but all the croppers I have found is only with rectangles? I haven't found one yet, where it can be a polygon?

Comment: in original question you asked the rectangle or polygon - there are different plugins. Some of them draw the circle, for example. Polygon cropping is hard to use and not obvious for the customers, so normally everyone uses simpler approach, you set one coordinate, pull and release, getting another coordinate and draw the rectangular area. This is standard functionality in every Operating System, in Photoshop, in web, whatever.